# Error Message using: sudo apt-get update command

Tags: apt, updates

This is the output I get while trying the `sudo apt-get update`
Running Ubuntu 16.10

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Answer (score 2):

First try to reboot and it should get fixed, if it doesn't and you're sure that their are no other running `apt` processes then run following commands, these commands might hurt something that they shouldn't. (you've been warned)

You can delete the lock file with the following command:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
```

You may also need to delete the lock file in the cache directory

```
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

After that, try updating again

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: thank you very much for your response, I will give this a try and hope that it will resolve the issue